# Dynamic condition on string in method

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
Float getPriceEqualsCategoryName(BrowseNode node, Float productPrice) {
    String name = node.getName();
    for (Entry<String, List<RangeValue>> entry : categoryToFee.entrySet()) {
        if (name.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            List<RangeValue> values = entry.getValue();
            for (RangeValue value : values) {
                if (productPrice < value.getMinValue())
                    return value.getMinValue();
                if (value.getRange().contains(productPrice))
                    return value.getReferPercentFee() / 100 * productPrice;
            }
        }
    }
    if (node.getAncestors() == null)
        return 0f;
    return getPriceEqualsCategoryName(node.getAncestors().getBrowseNode().get(0), productPrice);
}
```

In the above method I have to loop over something similar to tree structure bottom up and check if the name of the node EQUALS to entry name in the map. if yes - I will calculate the price according to it.

As a second choice, I need to loop again to check if the name CONTAINS the entry name in the map.

I wrote a similar method:

```
Float getPriceContainsCategoryName(BrowseNode node, Float productPrice) {
        String name = node.getName();
        for (Entry<String, List<RangeValue>> entry : categoryToFee.entrySet()) {
            if (name.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                List<RangeValue> values = entry.getValue();
                for (RangeValue value : values) {
                    if (productPrice < value.getMinValue())
                        return value.getMinValue();
                    if (value.getRange().contains(productPrice))
                        return value.getReferPercentFee() / 100 * productPrice;
                }
            }
        }
        if (node.getAncestors() == null)
            return 0f;
        return getPriceContainsCategoryName(node.getAncestors().getBrowseNode().get(0), productPrice);
    }
```

As you see, the only difference is the name.equals vs name.contains in the 4th line.

I don't like this duplicated code.. is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

Going on a hunch here, but may I suppose that you have something similar to the following to determine which method to call?

```
if (exactMatch) {
    getPriceEqualsCategoryName(node, productPrice);
} else {
    getPriceContainsCategoryName(node, producePrice);
}
```

If that is the case, and without delving too much into further refactoring the logic for this step, it may be more convenient, or easier, to pass `exactMatch` as an argument to a generic method:

```
float getPriceForMatchingCategoryName(final BrowseNode node, float productPrice, 
        boolean exactMatch) {
    final String name = node.getName();
    for (final Entry<String, List<RangeValue>> entry : categoryToFee.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        if (name.contains(key) && (!exactMatch || name.equals(key))) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

(I have taken the liberty to change `Float` to `float` to eliminate some auto-boxing.)

Using interfaces or lambdas is still *ok*, but I can't help but feel that these will be overblown solutions for a small piece of `boolean` logic. As illustrated, `exactMatch` is used as a secondary condition after `name.contains(key)` since `contains()` is the encompassing condition for both. If an exact match is not required, the primary condition will satisfy, else we will also perform `name.equals(key)`.

The downside is that two comparisons will be done for `equals()`, so if you have some really strict performance ceiling *and* this is indeed one of the last bottlenecks to eliminate, then you should just use a simpler `if` statement to switch between the comparisons to perform.

**Step 2**

The next refactoring step that you may want to consider is to abstract the double-`if` pricing logic somewhere else. The other answers suggested putting them into a method, but can they be regarded as to sufficiently 'belong' to the `RangeValue` class itself? If so, the body of the `if` clause above can be simplified as such:

```
// Using Java 8 interfaces with default methods to do my own 'stubbing'
private static interface RangeValue {
    float getMinValue();

    Collection<Float> getRange();

    float getReferPercentFee();

    default boolean isEligiblePrice(float price) {
        return price < getMinValue() || getRange().contains(Float.valueOf(price));
    }

    default float getPrice(float price) {
        return price < getMinValue() ? getMinValue() : getReferPercentFee() / 100 * price;
    }
}

////

if (name.contains(key) && (!exactMatch || name.equals(key))) {
    for (final RangeValue current : entry.getValue()) {
        if (current.isEligiblePrice(productPrice)) {
            return current.getPrice(productPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

The final, *minor* refactoring you can do is to simplify your last `return` statement:

```
float getPriceForMatchingCategoryName(final BrowseNode node, float productPrice,
        boolean exactMatch) {
    final String name = node.getName();
    for (final Entry<String, List<RangeValue>> entry : categoryToFee.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        if (name.contains(key) && (!exactMatch || name.equals(key))) {
            for (final RangeValue current : entry.getValue()) {
                if (current.isEligiblePrice(productPrice)) {
                    return current.getPrice(productPrice);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return node.getAncestors() == null ? 0f : getPriceForMatchingCategoryName(
        node.getAncestors().getBrowseNode().get(0), productPrice, exactMatch);
}
```

Comment: I liked the first refactoring. However, I didn't understand the RangeValue approach - how do I implement it? it's a class today not an interface

Comment: You just need to include the two methods proposed. I had to 'stub' `RangeValue` as an interface in my own testing since I do not know the original code to that class. ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Extract Duplication**

You could extract parts of the duplication to their own method:

```
private Float someResonableName(Float productPrice, List<RangeValue> values) {
    for (RangeValue value : values) {
        if (productPrice < value.getMinValue()) {
            return value.getMinValue();
        }
        if (value.getRange().contains(productPrice)) {
            return value.getReferPercentFee() / 100 * productPrice;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
        if (name.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            Float result = someResonableName(productPrice, entry.getValue());
            if (result != -1) {
                return result;
            }
        }
```

**Use Interface**

You could also use an interface:

```
interface NameKeyRelation {
    boolean isRelation(String name, RangeValue key);
}

Float getPriceContainsCategoryName(BrowseNode node, Float productPrice) {
    return getPriceContainsCategoryName(node, productPrice, (String name, RangeValue key) ->  name.contains(key)));
}

Float getPriceEqualsCategoryName(BrowseNode node, Float productPrice) {
    return getPriceContainsCategoryName(node, productPrice, (String name, RangeValue key) ->  name.equals(key)));
}

Float getPriceCategoryName(BrowseNode node, Float productPrice, NameKeyRelation relation) {
    String name = node.getName();
    for (Entry<String, List<RangeValue>> entry : categoryToFee.entrySet()) {
        if (relation.isRelation(name, entry.getKey())) {
            Float result = someResonableName(productPrice, entry.getValue());
            if (result != -1) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    if (node.getAncestors() == null)
        return 0f;
    return getPriceCategoryName(node.getAncestors().getBrowseNode().get(0), productPrice);
}
```

**Restructure**

It seems that your method currently does two things: It finds a category by name, and it calculate/finds some kind of price for a category. I would write two completely separate methods for each tasks, and then try to reduce duplication.

Comment: how can I use the interface?

Comment: @Odelya like in my example code (which is more psydo-code and might have typos, etc). I used Java8 lambda syntax, but you could also use the old fashioned way with `new NameKeyRelation() { public boolean isRelation(String name, RangeValue key) {return name.equals(key);}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can extract everything you do in the if-condition to another method and reuse that method in both cases. I.e. extract this bit and pass entry to it as a parameter and return a value.

```
            List<RangeValue> values = entry.getValue();
            for (RangeValue value : values) {
                if (productPrice < value.getMinValue())
                    return value.getMinValue();
                if (value.getRange().contains(productPrice))
                    return value.getReferPercentFee() / 100 * productPrice;
            }
```

Alternatively you can pass a boolean flag `exactMatch` to your existing method and either check for equals or contains based on that flag.